# jqgrid error message on delete

Tags: jqgrid

I've added the following code for my jqgrid:

```
changeTextFormat = function (data) {

                return "Activity or one from the same price group already used";
            };
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {errorTextFormat: changeTextFormat }
```

)

It works great for insert and I get the error message appearing in the top of the dialog.

However I want something similiar for deletes. I want to make it that if during my server side delete I find a problem with the operation I throw an exception.

Based on this exception I want to pop up an error message.

Can anybody tell me how to go about this for the delete function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting `$.jgrid.edit` is not the only setting which are used during form editing. There are also  `$.jgrid.del`, `$.jgrid.nav`, `$.jgrid.search` and `$.jgrid.view` which can be used.

If you need to define default implementation of `errorTextFormat` callback you can use

```
$.extend($.jgrid.del, { errorTextFormat: changeTextFormat });
```

in the same way like you use it with `$.jgrid.edit`.